# How to make XCode to detect "command click of selected text" on console?

Tags: ios, xcode, plugins

```
  ViewController *objViewController = [[ViewController alloc]init];
```

In Xcode, in above line if I "command+click" on "ViewController" on editing area, Xcode detects the symbol and corresponding file will be opened in Xcode.

During debugging, I am printing the same ViewController in console area of Xcode. However there "command+click" on ViewController, don't work.

Is there any plugin or any shortcut, instead of copying the text and search for file. The actual intention is to make debugging easier.

Thanks...